# Executing code from code review request without affecting my workspace in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-code-review

I see there is an option to execute code from code review request without affecting my workspace using visual studio.

reference:

http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/team-collaboration-vs.aspx

But, i dont find information on how to do it? any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Premium or higher (which you must be if you can do code reviews) you can use the **My Work** area of TFS (under Team Explorer) to put your current work on hold before carrying out the code review (which performs in the same way as 1 below) by choosing **suspend**, when you have finished with the review you can then restart your work which will reset your IDE to the state it was in when you paused your work.

An example of the developer workflow for code reviews and suspending work can be found on MSDN [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh474795.aspx)

The code review will contain the code in a shelveset, in order to execute code locally it will need to be downloaded to your workspace.

If you were performing the same task without the suspend Feature of my work, you could mimic the behaviour in 2 ways

1. Shelve all of your current changes / neutralise your workspace before begining the code review
2. Create an alternative workspace and use this for code reviews, this will leave your normal workspace in its current state.

Comment: So, from my link, http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/team-collaboration-vs.aspx, feature "Review and execute code without affecting your work space" under code review, is not a feature out of the box?

Comment: yes it is out of the box, if you use the My Work Suspend feature, sorry was trying to explain what happens.